# Can't understand D seperation

Tags: bayesian-network

I have the following network:

[image]

I am told that B is independant of D. Why is this the case? Shouldnt that they are both connected to C break that independence based on the V shape?

[image]

In this case, I am told that B is not indep of D. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graphical model is the graphical representation of conditional probabilities.

So, your question can be answered by checking what set of conditional probabilities the model assumes.

---

#### Above figure

By definition, your model is equivalent to the following set of equations :

$$
\begin{aligned}
P (A, B, C, D) &= P(A) P(B|A) P(C|B) P(C |D)  \\[7pt]
P (C | A) &= \sum_{b \in B} P (C | b) P(b | A)\\[7pt]
P(B|D) &= P (B)
\end{aligned}
$$

thus by definition $P(B|D) = P (B)$.

(Further, you can show that $P(D | C ) \neq P(B  |C)$)

---

#### Below figure

Again by definition,

$$
\begin{aligned}
P (A, B, C, D) &= P(D) P(C|D) P(B|C, D) P(A|B)  \\[7pt]
P (A | C) &= \sum_{b \in B} P (A | b) P(b | C) \\[7pt]
P (B | D) &= \sum_{c \in C} P (B | D, c)
\end{aligned}
$$

note that $P (B | D) \neq P(B)$